# Cannot call methods from my classes

Tags: asp.net, methods

I'm not an expert, but I have to download dlls and use created classes for make integrations with a document platform,

I found some classes and I included in my web site, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Cache;
using System.Net.Http;
using DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient;

public class Conectador
{
    public Conectador()
    {}

    static Uri uri = new Uri("http://192.168.0.63/docuware/platform");

    public static ServiceConnection Connect()
    {
        return ServiceConnection.Create(uri, "administrador", "@dmm0N");
    }

public static ServiceConnection ConnectWithUserAgent()
{
    return ServiceConnection.Create(uri, "administrador", "@dmm0N",
        userAgent: new System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue[] {
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue("DocuWare+.NET+API+Test+Client", "1.0")
        });
}

public static ServiceConnection ConnectWithOrg()
{
    return ServiceConnection.Create(uri, "administrador", "@dmm0N", organization: "Digital Solution Digitsol S.A.");
}

public static ServiceConnection ConnectWithCaching()
{
    var handler = new WebRequestHandler() { CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Default) };
    return ServiceConnection.Create(uri, "administrador", "@dmm0N", httpClientHandler: handler);
}



}
```

When I try to call them in my commands I can't:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _01_Conexion : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Conectador cn = new Conectador();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      cn....     => I have nothing Here!!!
}
}
```

What am I missing? What's my error?
I hope anyone please can help me...

Best regards

Comment: Can you please come up with an actual title instead of just spamming caps-lock.

Comment: Ok, I did it Julian

Comment: Well, you just made the title lowercase. However, this title is not very descriptive in terms of your question.

Comment: So your problem is that you can not call cn from within the Button1_Click method?

Comment: Thanks Julian. Yes, mi problem is that, I can not, call them.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to declare the field cn of your class outside of the constructor. I don't program in c# but i assume, that it is scoped to your constructor and so not existing in your other method.